# django rest framework add write only field for unit conversion

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write an API allowing users to read a length in km but write it in miles. The model stores the information in kilometers.

The idea is to achieve something like this:

```
class AreaSizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AreaSize
        fields = ['width', 'height']

    # This function should perform the unit conversion
    def write_width(self, miles):
        self.width = miles * 1.609344

    ...
```

So when the user performs a POST request containing the size in miles it gets converted to kilometers and stored in the database.

Could somebody please explain how to do this?

Comment: If you really want to do this in the serializer, consider using a validator(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation).

Comment: You can set `write_only` option on a new field you add to your serializer. But it's not clear whether your API should accept either km or mi as input (i.e. the miles value would have a different name, e.g. `width_miles` or **only** miles as input. If not, then you only need to override the validation, and return the km as validated value.

Comment: @dirkgroten that does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Override `save` and `update` methods in your `AreaSizeSerializer` class to perform unit conversion on the width field whenever it is saved or updated.

```
class AreaSizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AreaSize
        fields = ['width', 'height']

    def width_mi_to_km(self, width):
        return 1.609344 * width

    def save(self, validated_data):
        area_size = {
            **validated_data, 
            'width': self.width_mi_to_km(validated_data['width'])
        }
        return super().save(area_size)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        area_size = {
            **validated_data, 
            'width': self.width_mi_to_km(validated_data['width'])
        }
        return super().update(instance, area_size)
```